# Parallel processing on multiple cores fails on some processes

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, multicore

I have the following issue on a 64 core multi cluster.
I try to run a bash file, which looks like this:

```
nohup command01 > nohup.output01 &
nohup command02 > nohup.output02 &
...
nohup command50 > nohup.output50 &
```

However, if I look at the output files or use the htop command, it seems like that only around 40 of my 50 jobs are running. And it seems to be just randomly, which of the 50 were chosen/processed. The others were started (There are a few lines written in the output files), but suddenly stopped. I tried to reduce the numbers to 30,20 ... always some jobs missing. 
Now I'm running the first 10, having started those, I do another 10 - this seems to work (20 jobs in parallel). But it's annoying. So my question: How can it happen, that not all 50 jobs can be processed in parallel on a 64-core multi cluster and can I do anything to get it working ?
I can't find any error in the outputs. 
Thanks for any help, B.

Comment: What's in `command01..50`? What happens if you replace the contents of `command01..50` with something like `sleep 10 && echo Done`? Ans what is the OS? And what is a `multi cluster`?

Comment: Hi Mark !
1. The command is in general registering images onto each other.
I just notice that all the commands are using the same input image, so
`command01: register image01 to GeneralImage
command02: register image02 to GeneralImage
...
command50: register image50 to GeneralImage`
2. I don't understand what you mean with the sleep command. So do you mean I should add that line after each command ?
3. I am using Ubuntu and use ssh to run on the multi-core machine.
4. Sorry for being not specific, the machine consists of a cluster of 64 cores. So "multi core" rather than "multi cluster" :-)

Comment: I meant to replace the entire contents of each of the 50 scripts with a simple script that just sleeps and echoes some output and see if your cluster can handle 50 simple processes. if it can, then the issue is likely in your scripts. If it can't do 50 sleeps, then the issue is with the OS and cluster.

Comment: Ah now I see, thanks Mark. Alright, I'll try that. But if the issue is in my script, isn't it strange that I don't get any error messages then ? Seems like some job gets paused but are never finished.

Comment: Given that all your output files had output in them, that's an indication that they all ran. That they didn't produce the output you wanted is an artifact of your commandXX programs. Perhaps that's where you should look?